# return a list of data of any type from ado.net instead of DataTable

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am writing a ADO.Net Wrapper class as an alternative of ORM

I don't want any ORM in my Application because there is not requirement of ORM just want to keep my code less , so thinking of automating ADO.Net task in reusable functions

Below is some of my code for this wrapper class

```
internal class adoWrapper
{
    public string _connectionString { get; set; }

    public adoWrapper(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string Query, List<ParametersGroup> Parameters)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query))
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Query Parameter Can not be Null or Empty");
        }
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con))
            {
                if (Parameters != null && Parameters.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Count; i++)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(Parameters[i].paramName, Parameters[i].paramValue);
                    }
                }
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                con.Open();
                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    public object ExecuteScalar(string Query, List<ParametersGroup> Parameters)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query))
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Query Parameter Can not be Null or Empty");
        }
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con))
            {
                if (Parameters != null && Parameters.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Count; i++)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(Parameters[i].paramName, Parameters[i].paramValue);
                    }
                }
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                con.Open();
                return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
    }



    public DataTable ExecuteQuery(string Query, List<ParametersGroup> Parameters)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query))
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Query Parameter Can not be Null or Empty");
        }
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con))
            {
                if (Parameters != null && Parameters.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Count; i++)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(Parameters[i].paramName, Parameters[i].paramValue);
                    }
                }
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    ad.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
}

public class ParametersGroup
{
    public string paramName { get; set; }

    public string paramValue { get; set; }
}
```

In last method

```
public DataTable ExecuteQuery(string Query, List<ParametersGroup> Parameters)
```

I don't want to return result in Datatable . instead I want to return a list like Entity Framework does.

For example if I have two tables ,

Table A and

Table B

and I am running select * query from them than it should return

List<<"Table A">> or

List<<"Table B">>

But the Problem is at run time I don't know that the returned result is of which class type (whether its a class model of Table A or Table B ) . and there can be n number of tables .

How can I achieve this in C# ?

Comment: You're creating an ORM because my application doesn't need an ORM but I want to be able to do what an ORM does without using an ORM? Maybe you should just use an ORM.

Comment: You would need to write a generic method and then use Reflection on the generic type parameter to get the names and types of properties and then map data from like-named `DataColumns` or fields in a data reader.

Comment: You can define the `ExecuteQuery` as `ExecuteQuery<T>` which would return the type as T. However, this would require to pass the type of `T` while invoking. Let me know if this you want. would provide the code sample for it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , men you made me smile like Spiderman of avengers - #ORM , But ORM have so many things that slow down the execution which I am trying to ignore  and I am hardly gonna need 7 or 8 method to automate this because that what I need , not everything like  fully feature ORM EF or Dapper

Comment: @user1672994 that sounds like it will work , any post you can refer for that ?

Comment: If you don't know resulting type, you are going to the reflection any way. @Jack, why are you thinking, that your hand-made-ORM will work faster with reflections then EF does (for ex.)?

Comment: @vasily.sib I am going to add less layer (I hope) as compare to EF

Comment: @user1672994 , Can you post that solution again , I have to try that

Comment: @Jack - Need to fix that code, let me rework and post it again.

Comment: Dapper seems to me like an obvious choice here. It's a micro-orm built for speed, so it doesn't have all that big heavy stuff that EF does. I would at least consider testing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want return list of element out of you call, then you need to create you own maaper classes which can map value from datatabel to your boject, I did as below code in my project

```
namespace DataTableToObjectMappper
{
    public interface IMapper<T>
    {
        T MapDataRow(DataRow dr);
        List<T> MapDataTable(DataTable dt);
    }
}

//like employee mapper you need to create mapper for you object
//you can also make use of reflection instead of going for each property as done below 
   public class EmployeeMapper : IMapper<Employee>
    {
        public Employee MapDataRow(DataRow dr)
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee()
            {
                Id = ServiceUtil.GetColumnValue<float>("Id", dr),
                Name = ServiceUtil.GetColumnValue<string>("Name", dr),
                Address = ServiceUtil.GetColumnValue<int>("Address", dr),                
            };
            return emp;
        }

        public List<Employee> MapDataTable(DataTable dt)
        {
            List<Employee> lst = new List<Employee>();
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows != null)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    lst.Add(MapDataRow(dr));
                }
            }
            return lst;
        }
    }

    public static T GetColumnValue<T>(string columnName, DataRow dr)
    {
        Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);

        return dr.Table.Columns.Contains(columnName) && dr[columnName] != DBNull.Value
            ? (T) Convert.ChangeType(dr[columnName] , typeParameterType)
            : default(T);
    }
```

call it by using like this

```
  new EmployeeMapper().MapDataTable(dt);
```

Comment: in this you already know that result is of Employee Type  , That's not my scenario  , My Type is unknown

Comment: @Jack - you dont know what is going be retuned than how you are going to cast you datatabel to object , by magic ?...ORM under the hood create classes mapped with database table and cast database table to object ..that how it works